# Tagging people in wall post with POST to Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp-1.3

I'm having some serious trouble with tagging people in a wall post. I'm working with CakePHP right now and using the FB API to POST to the Graph API. Here's the code:

```
    $theMsg1 = $this->Connect->user('name').' tagged ';
    $theMsg2 = $friendName.' on the IF Tag website.';
    $msg1Len = strlen($theMsg1);
    $fbNameLen = strlen($friendName);`

    $fbcall = FB::api($fbID.'/feed', 'POST', array(
        'name'    => $theTag['Tag']['name'],
        'caption' => 'IF Tag is an application that allows you to interact with people on Facebook.',
        'message' => $theMsg1.$theMsg2,
        'message_tags' => array(
            $msg1Len => array(
                'id' => $friendID,
                'name' => $friendName,
                'offset' => $msg1Len,
                'length' => $fbNameLen
            ),
            'picture' => 'http://patronsocialclub.com/img/global/head/drinkmaker.gif',
            'link' => 'iftag.local'
        )
    ));
```

From what I understand and what I've read I'm supposed to use the message_tags object to tag people in a post but it's not working at all. It doesn't give any errors, just doesn't tag.

I've also tried using `@[{userid}:1:{username}]` from other posts I've seen but that doesn't seem to work with the current iteration of the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer here [Facebook Graph API Post with_tags option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614574/facebook-graph-api-post-with-tags-option/11614915#11614915)

the gist of it is

I think what you want to use is just "tags" and it should just contain id's as specified here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

**note you cannot do this though without also specifying a place

Facebook have now released mention tagging which might be the solution you need https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/ but it requires custom open graph actions.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to tag a friend in a status update or post via the API.
It is in their wishlist here is the link

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/351412111599830