# Tag friends to the link in facebook application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, tagging

I have made an application on facebook, i have added link share option, comment for the link and like for the same link. Now what i want is the person who is generating the link can also tag his friends. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my previous answer to this question [Facebook Graph API Post with_tags option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614574/facebook-graph-api-post-with-tags-option/11614915#11614915) you need to specify a 'place' to do this as far as I'm aware

EDIT****

According to the developer blog, you can now use mention tagging which might be what you want
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/