# Tag someone on a feed dialog with Facebook API

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using this code to share a picture on facebook.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "13899290", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          redirect_uri: 'YOUR URL HERE',
          link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
          picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
          caption: 'Reference Documentation',
          description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i would like to tag someone who is on the picture. How can i achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you guys sure it is not possible. I'm sure i have seen this somewhere recently

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, you cant tag people on feed dialog, but only the pictures using the **tags** param in "**/photos**".

The **[Tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/tagging/)** concept is available only for the Open Graph stories.

**UPDATE:**

You can tag a person only with a valid **place** parameter(if you want to hide the place in post, give any valid page id instead), the post will look something like-

---

[image]

I guess, this is the only possible solution for tagging the friends in a post if you are not using the open graph

Comment: How do you add a place parameter to the feed dialog? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ doesn't seem to mention it

Comment: I'm not sure of Feed Dialog, but place is a valid parameter if you post via `API`

Answer (score 3):

FB.ui method `'feed'` is the equivalent to POSTing to the `/USER_ID/feed` Graph API endpoint, which creates *posts*.  And there is currently no way to create tags for *posts* using the api.

Ref:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/247911678652789

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Alternatively, you could upload a photo to an album (or to /me/photos) and include tags for the photo:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/  [see 'tags: create' section]

This is how I take a user uploaded file and publish it with tags:

```
// Upon successful file (photo) upload.
$FILEPATH = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

// upload it to FB.
$args = array(
  'name' => 'Testing photo upload via php-SDK!',
  'source' => '@'.realpath($FILEPATH),
  'tags' => array(
    array('tag_uid' => USER_ID, 'x' => 20, 'y' => 40),
  )
);
$post_id = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed, but i don't want to save the photo in an album.I just need to publish a feed dialog WITH tags (using their ids)...
Are you guys sure it is not possible. I'm sure i have seen this somewhere recently

Answer (score 2):

For the feed tagging, see my previous answers here [Facebook Graph API Post with_tags option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614574/facebook-graph-api-post-with-tags-option/11614915#11614915)

To summarise you basically need to use mention tagging

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/mention-tagging/

Answer (score 2):

Found this one [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed):

> For example the following message would mention the Facebook
>   Developers page inline:

```
Test message @[19292868552] tag
```

But your app must be reviewed first.

Answer (score 1):

You can't tag images in a Post to the NewsFeed (/home) or a user's Wall (/feed). See the [Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) for Posts to feed. There is no tag-related parameter.

> I'm sure i have seen this somewhere recently

What you have seen may be photo uploads, which *do* appear in the feed, but are not classified as posts to the newsfeed by the API. Photo uploads accept tag attributes. See Graph APi docs for [Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/).