# How do I tag friends in posts that are automatically produced by a mobile app?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Our app is a head to head game and when the match is over- we post who won the bet.
We currently post "@John Smith beat @Adam Rogers!" but the people aren't tagged.
What needs to written in order to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What needs to written in order to do so?

You are looking for the [**Mention Tagging**](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/21/bringing-mention-tagging-to-open-graph/). It's an Open Graph concept- and the only way to tag friends on the post.

If you are new to Open Graph, you can start from here: [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

---

Yet, there's a workaround, but I don't prefer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024103/1343690