# Tagging friends on Facebook using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have developed an app in PHP which
*1.* process some data on friends of the user (*extracted using taggable_friends*) and then generates an image and save it on the app server.
*2.* Shows the image to the user and offers option to share the image on their timeline.
*3.* Now I need to tag some friends also in that timeline post *[as I should use taggable_friends for tagging also not just for getting friends of the user as per Fb guidelines]*.

I'm using this code to get list of friends

```
$friends = $fb->get('/me/taggable_friends?fields=name,first_name,id,picture.width(80).height(80)&limit=500')->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
```

---

But I don't know how to tag the friends [using PHP] on the timeline while sharing using Javascript. Please help. I can't find an answer to do this job which still works in 2016.

---

Javascript code to share

```
function shareOnFacebook() {
var response = '';
 FB.ui(
  {
   method: 'share',
    href: linkToShare,
  },
   function(response) {
   if (response && response.post_id) { } else {
     alert('Something went wrong !');
    }
   }
     );
 };
```

Comment: Before negative voting post either the answer or a useful link OR comment below so I can have a chat with you. 
:x :D

Comment: well, we got a brutus. More to follow .

Comment: Could you share the code you are using to share the post currently?

Comment: @Matt I've added the JS code

Comment: view [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614574/facebook-graph-api-post-with-tags-option/11614915#11614915) answer and other in this question